# Right using of String lastIndexOf

Tags: java

I have string `String str ="12,123 123!abc123.abc"` with `,.!` delimiters and I want to delete last 123. If I use `StringBuffer str1c = new StringBuffer(str)` and use `int last = str1c.lastIndexOf("123")` i'll get last = 14. But it is wrong, because want to get index of clear "123", without any letters near. I want to make `str1c ="12,123 !abc123.abc"`

Comment: You want to use a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a **regular expression** and as you need to only replace the last match, you will need to reverse everything using [`StringBuilder#reverse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse--) and use a **reversed regular expression** so instead of using `\b123\b` we use `\b321\b`, so your final code will be:

```
String result = new StringBuilder(
    new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString().replaceFirst("\\b321\\b", "")
).reverse().toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

**Output:**

```
12,123 !abc123.abc
```